# Integrating $y' = \sin^2 y$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve: $$y' = \sin^2 y$$

It is a separable variable differential equation, so I arrive to

$$\int\frac{dy}{\sin^2 y}=\int dx$$

I use the identity $$\sin^2 y=\frac{1-\cos(2y)}{1}$$ and then finally get:

$$y - \frac{1}{2}\sin(2y) = 2x + C$$

But the given solution is $$y = \rm {arccot} (-x+C)$$

Where is the problem in my solution?

Comment: Note: $\int\frac{1}{\sin(y)^2}dy=-\cot(y)$.  It looks like you integerated $\int\sin(y)^2 dy$ instead.

Comment: @GEdgar you are right, silly mistake!

Answer (score 2):

Your integral is wrong.

The equation is seperable autonomous so we divide both sides by $\sin^2 y$ to get
$$\csc^2 y\cdot y' = 1$$
which we integrate wrt x to get (use the definition $(\cot x)'=-\csc^2 x$)
$$-\cot y = x+C$$
$$\implies y=\operatorname{arccot} (-x-C)$$
and we just collect the "-" into the constant to get the desired solution